# UI Grid - Save and restore state not accurate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I try to save and restore the state of the grid but it is somehow not accurate for me. I try other grid options as well but everytime I restore the state, the scrolling position is not back to the former state and it moves up 4 or 5 rows.

For example, if I move to the last row and save the state. I cannot restore to the last row. Thanks.

```
  $scope.saveState = function() {
    $scope.state = $scope.gridApi.saveState.save();
  };

  $scope.restoreState = function() {
    $scope.gridApi.saveState.restore( $scope, $scope.state );
  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VDi8ZNw9oevUL2lkPYqu